# Playwright - can't see tests

Tags: reactjs, playwright

I have playwright tests in `/src/components/....`
And in `src/utils/playwright` I have a `auth.setup.ts` file for login.

Here is my config file:

```
import { defineConfig, devices } from "@playwright/test";

export default defineConfig({
  // Look for test files in the "tests" directory, relative to this configuration file.
  testDir: "src",

  // Run all tests in parallel.
  fullyParallel: true,

  // Fail the build on CI if you accidentally left test.only in the source code.
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,

  // Retry on CI only.
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,

  // Opt out of parallel tests on CI.
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,

  // Reporter to use
  reporter: "html",

  use: {
    // Base URL to use in actions like `await page.goto('/')`.
    baseURL: "http://localhost:3000/",

    // Collect trace when retrying the failed test.
    trace: "on-first-retry",
  },
  // Configure projects for major browsers.
  projects: [
    {
      name: "setup",
      testMatch: '**/*.setup.ts',
    },
    // {
    //   name: "chromium-unauthenticated",
    //   testMatch: '**/src/**/*.unauthenticated.spec.ts',
    //   testIgnore: [
    //     '**/*.{spec-ct,test}.(ts|js)',
    //     '**/src/components/**/*.test.{ts,tsx}',
    //   ],
    // },
    {
      name: "chromium-authenticated",
      testMatch: '**/*.spec.ts',
      testIgnore: [
        '**/*.{spec-ct,test}.(ts|js)',
        '**/src/components/**/*.test.{ts,tsx}',
        '.*.unauthenticated.spec.ts',
      ],
    },
  ],
  
  // Run your local dev server before starting the tests.
  webServer: {
    command: "yarn dev",
    url: "http://localhost:3000/",
    reuseExistingServer: !process.env.CI,
    timeout: 120 * 1000,
  },
});
```

The proble is that...
if I have both

```
{
  name: "setup",
  testMatch: '**/*.setup.ts',
},
```

and

```
{
  name: "chromium-authenticated",
  testMatch: '**/*.spec.ts',
  testIgnore: [
    '**/*.{spec-ct,test}.(ts|js)',
    '**/src/components/**/*.test.{ts,tsx}',
    '.*.unauthenticated.spec.ts',
  ],
},
```

the playwright gui shows me only the `setup("authenticate", async ({ context }) => {...` that is inside the `auth.setup.ts`.

If I comment

```
{
  name: "setup",
  testMatch: '**/*.setup.ts',
},
```

and I leave only:

```
{
  name: "chromium-authenticated",
  testMatch: '**/*.spec.ts',
  testIgnore: [
    '**/*.{spec-ct,test}.(ts|js)',
    '**/src/components/**/*.test.{ts,tsx}',
    '.*.unauthenticated.spec.ts',
  ],
},
```

Then it shows me the `.spec.ts` file that is inside `/src/components/foldername/testfile.spec.ts`

I want both tests to be there at the same time.

Am I doing something wrong or it's a playwright bug?

**EDIT:**

I also tried to have only regext and avoid a mix of regex and glob patterns.
There is the same issue.

With the following:

```
  projects: [
    {
      name: "chromium-authenticated",
      testMatch: /.*\.spec\.ts$/,
      testIgnore: [
        /.*\.(spec-ct|test)\.(ts|js)$/,
        /.*\/src\/components\/.*\.test\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        /.*\.unauthenticated\.spec\.ts$/,
      ],
    },
    {
      name: "setup",
      testMatch: /.*\.setup\.ts$/,
    },
  ],
```

I see only the "chromium-authenticated" tests.

If I change position I see only the setup tests:

```
  projects: [
    {
      name: "setup",
      testMatch: /.*\.setup\.ts$/,
    },
    {
      name: "chromium-authenticated",
      testMatch: /.*\.spec\.ts$/,
      testIgnore: [
        /.*\.(spec-ct|test)\.(ts|js)$/,
        /.*\/src\/components\/.*\.test\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        /.*\.unauthenticated\.spec\.ts$/,
      ],
    },
  ],
```

So it means that the 'earliest' stops and doesn't go next.

Comment: how are you executing these suites ? Please share the complete command.

Comment: I am running this script: "test-pui": "playwright test --ui",

Comment: I made a new edit to the original question

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your script is trying to authenticate.
There're 2 ways:

1. [global.setup.ts](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-global-setup-teardown#setup) -  produces traces or artifacts
2. [globalSetup](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-global-setup-teardown#configure-globalsetup-and-globalteardown): require.resolve('./global-setup') - no traces or artifacts.

Looks like you forgot to add **dependencies: ['setup']** in your solution:

```js
projects: [
    {
      name: 'setup',
      testMatch: /global.setup\.ts/,
    },
    {
      name: 'chromium',
      use: { ...devices['Desktop Chrome'] },
      dependencies: ['setup'],
    },
  ]
```

Note: You don't need to change anything else. If it didn't work try the second option. You don't need to add anything except requiring your global-setup file in config.